# Can I monitor pictures taken by Android native camera app via my app?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I want my app to monitor android native camera app in the background and warn the user if the scene is appropriate for him to capture. Is there any way to have maybe an intent or callback to receive?

Comment: What do you mean by "appropiate"?

Comment: Like checking the light intensity, or if the scene (place) is not allowed to be captured.

Answer (score 1):

> I want my app to monitor android native camera app

There is no single "android native camera app". There are thousands upon thousands of Android device models. Those devices ship with hundreds of different camera apps pre-installed.

Of course, there are also many more camera apps that are available for download from places like the Play Store.

> Is there any way to have maybe an intent or callback to receive?

There is no requirement that any camera app save a picture in a place that your app can access. The app might save it to internal storage, or to the app's private location on removable storage, or send it directly to a server — you can access none of these from your app, let alone monitor them.

You are welcome to attempt to use `FileObserver` to monitor for file changes in places where you think that camera apps might put files out on external storage. You may get some false positives (files put there that are not photos taken by the camera). Also, this will only work while your app is running, and usually your app cannot run all the time.

Comment: Thank you for the response. So there is no way to monitor camera feed in android in the background like an anti virus which checks for malicious activity in PC?

Comment: @Dr.Trax: Correct, not in any way that is guaranteed to work for all camera apps and all users.